# Removing next element from a list via a variable

Tags: python, list, variables

Okay this might sound somewhat confusing, but bear with me.

I basically have a list. Let's call this list say `myList`
This list is being called via a variable, such as:

```
myVariable = myList[0]
```

I'm setting the variable as the result of the first element in the list. 
Now basically what I want to do is to remove the next element (such as 1) from the myList, then set the result in a variable.

How could I go about to do this?

Comment: You mean being indexed.  You can't call a list.

Comment: Pop it off: `myList.pop(1)`

Answer (score 1):

```
myList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
myVariable = myList.pop(1)
print myList
print myVariable
```

Comment: To be clear, this pops the element at index 1. It's not looking for the value 1.